# How to denoise an image using java opencv

Tags: java, opencv

In my case I want to remove the all black dots of my image. here my image can be presented as follows. when i was doing using my program the image was smoothing how ever the program doesn't remove the black dots. please help me to remove black dots.please reply me soon
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybD8q.jpg)
 the codes are as follows.

```
public class Denoise {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
         Mat source =Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\Users\\My Kindom\\Downloads\\printscreen.JPG",Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

         Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());
         destination = source;
         Photo.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(source,destination, 10, 10, 7, 21);
         Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:\\Users\\My Kindom\\Downloads\\Denoise.jpg", destination);

        }catch(Exception e){}
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
```

[Destination Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7pny.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, you can apply a threshold to segment the black dots. Then, using this as a mask, do an inpainting. Inpainting won't affect other regions of the image as denoising. I'm not quite sure what you mean by black dots, so I've applied a simple threshold. You can try with different thresholds, use *inRange* or whatever to produce the mask. I'm also using an arbitrary inpainting-radius. You may be able to make it better by analyzing contour areas in the mask and then deciding on a radius.

**original**

[image: original]

**mask and inpainted: threshold = 70, radius = 20**

[image: mask70][image: dn70]

**mask and inpainted: threshold = 100, radius = 20**

[image: mask100][image: dn100]

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.photo.Photo;

public class Dnoise {

    public static void doDnoise()
    {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        Mat rgb = Highgui.imread("ybD8q.jpg");

        Mat gray = new Mat(rgb.size(), CvType.CV_8U);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(rgb, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Mat mask = new Mat(rgb.size(), CvType.CV_8U);
        Imgproc.threshold(gray, mask, 70, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
        Mat dn = new Mat(rgb.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Photo.inpaint(rgb, mask, dn, 20, Photo.INPAINT_TELEA);
    }

}
```