# Horizontal Lines on Webcam Feed because of LED Flickering on Openframeworks + OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, openframeworks

I am having [horizontal lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjRiq.jpg) in my webcam feed in Openframeworks and I am using a Playstation Eye cam with ofxPS3EyeGrabber to achieve this. I have also tried opencvexample sketch but it looks like the same.

For the context, I am trying to create a real-time hand drawing tracker by using a webcam , lighttable and some transparencies. So the idea is to digitalize the drawn sketch on a transparent acrylic sheet by using computer (similar to an overhead projector). The setup is similar to “Where do you call home?” by Peter Thompson (2008) https://vimeo.com/122126723.

I have also checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432652/solving-camera-bad-feedbackseveral-shades-of-horizontal-lines-moving-up-and-dow) but I can't solve my problem with the suggested solutions.

Does anyone have an idea how I can tackle this problem?

Comment: If you want to remove those lines, try inpainting. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36749867/2571705) might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some white LEDs or IR light to do the illumination. But you should strobe them when the webcam captures the frame.

There was a good example on how to do VSync in the EyeWriter [Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/The-EyeWriter-20/step9/Hacking-the-PS-Eye-camera-VSync/).
 I hope this is what you're looking for.